# Wireless keyboard sends duplicate events on Windows 10

Tags: keyboard

I have a Genius KB 8000x wireless keyboard. It used to work well for months until last week when it occurs that some key press is multiplied. Eg I press a space and twenty spaces are added. Or I press a backspace and several words are deleted. It happens randomly. Sometimes it helps to move a dongle to different USB port for a while.

I would think it is a hw problem of the keyboard. But I had similar problems with cheaper wireless keyboard of different vendor which I threw away. And the problem is back. Is this a problem of Windows 10? Or am I unlucky with amalfuncting device?

Comment: Have you thoroughly cleaned your keyboard? This behaviour can be caused by debris stuck under the keys.

Comment: Good idea. But my keyboard seems clean. I found similar thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a2c20718-643e-4d2a-8507-0930295c1d2d/keys-repeat-uncontrollably?forum=w7itprohardware

Comment: Could you test that keyboard by attaching it to another computer?

Comment: Also check that the driver is OK in Device Manager, or if there is an update.